# Thanks for six years!

Tags: discussion

In the six years since I was elected to be a moderator on GDSE, I've had a great time working with and supporting the community here.

But ends come to all things. I've found myself with less and less time to put towards the site recently, and so I've decided to step down as a moderator.

Thanks for this opportunity, it's been fun!

Comment: I'll miss your steady hand at the wheel! Thank you for everything you've done to build and maintain this community.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions and advice, game dev & otherwise. Hope you can still drop by from time to time. I wish you well on whatever comes next.

Comment: Thank you for the truly amazing amount of effort you've put into the site! ♥

Comment: Maybe he found a Singleton in the SE codebase.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if I should vote up because of all the help you've provided in shaping this community and all the high quality help you've provided to users over the years, or if I should vote down because I'm a little sad to see you go.

In any case, I think you're a great mod and I certainly looked up to you for that role.

I wish you luck and fun in your other projects, and we'll always be happy to see you answer a question on the main site :)